# Block kids from installing software

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Is there a software I can use to keep kids from downloading software and installing it on windows xp? (these are smart 12yr olds)

I only want them to be allowed to play flash games online.

Blocking the ability to download games with spyware and other not so good things. Limited account did not do anything.

Comment: Don't give them administrator rights....

Answer (score 6):

You don't need specific software for this. You only need to create accounts with limited rights for them, as opposed to the administrator account who can install anything. But default limited accounts don't do their job really well, so you'll have to tweak a little to make sure they can't do what you don't want them to do.

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/137228-45-limited-account-installing-software

This thread should have all the tools you need to do that.